# I can't copy in Arctic Fox .I am seeing a black like thing when I am trying to copy anything

Tags: android, kotlin, copy, copy-paste, android-studio-arctic-fox

[I am seeing this black like thing when I am trying to copy anything.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVudK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just switched to Insert Mode,Press Insert Key on Keyboard to get back to normal.